# how to insert two or more text into the same field in a databse using access oledb vb10

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

**i try to insert 10 record under the field year and actual data but only the first text from text1 is entering inside**
how to save the value from two or more textbox into the same field e.g years

```
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "db7exmpl.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        'str = " INSERT INTO tb (Years) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "," & TextBox3.Text & "," & TextBox5.Text & "');"
        str = "insert into tb ([Years], [Actual_data]) values (?, ?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox7.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox9.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox11.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox13.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox15.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox17.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Years", CType(TextBox19.Text, String)))

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox8.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox10.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox12.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox14.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox16.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox18.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_data", CType(TextBox20.Text, String)))
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'myConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to execute a separate query for each pair:

```
    Using cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=db7exmpl.accdb")
        cn.Open()
        For x = 1 To 19 Step 2
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TB ([Years], [Actual_Data]) VALUES (?,?)", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Years", CType(Controls("TextBox" & x), TextBox).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Actual_Data", CType(Controls("TextBox" & (x + 1)), TextBox).Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
```